# Scott Gu Dynamic Linq Convert Datetime to ShortDatetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, t-sql, dynamic-linq

I am using the Scott Gu Dynamic `Linq` class and I am trying to convert a datetime to return a short datetime before databinding the result set to a gridview in `ASP.net`.  Now, I know that I can go through the gridview row databound event and check each cell to see if it is a date, and if it is, convert the date to the shortdate, however that is very cumbersome and I do not feel it is very efficient.

I am building my select statement in DynamicLinq as follows:

Filter gets its information as follows:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dictFilters)
        {
            filter += kvp.Key + " as " + kvp.Value.Replace("-", "_").Replace(" ", "_") + ",";
        }


        var result = db.ViewADHOCContractInfos.Select("new(" + filter + ")");
```

which gives me the result set of:

```
    {SELECT [t0].[dtmAward] AS [Award_Date], [t0].[guidFromId],  [t0].[strFundingNumber] AS [Funding_Number], [t0].[dtmCertified] AS [Certified_Date], [t0].[strFundingNumberStatus] AS [Funding_Status]
FROM [dbo].[ViewADHOCInfo] AS [t0]
}
```

Now what I want is this:

```
   {SELECT Convert(VarChar, [t0].[dtmAward], 101) AS [Award_Date], [t0].[guidFromId],  [t0].[strFundingNumber] AS [Funding_Number], [t0].[dtmCertified] AS [Certified_Date], [t0].[strFundingNumberStatus] AS [Funding_Status]
FROM [dbo].[ViewADHOCInfo] AS [t0]
}
```

Is it possible to add a SQL convert to by select statement using Dynamic Linq?

Comment: @Icarus - asp.net, I will add that, sorry

Comment: What LINQ provider do you use? Because I only know how to do this with NHibernate and dynamic Linq.

Comment: @PatrickKoorevaar  I am using the regular LINQ library and have all of my tables connected to a DBML.  I am using the Dynamic Linq class provided by Scott Gu

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a formatting issue:

Simply set the DataFormatString property on the column as so:

```
DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyy}"
```

The full context:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateColumn" 
                    HeaderText="Date" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" />
```

Or to any suitable format for your case and the date will be formatted properly.

Comment: the columns are built on the fly, there is no definition of them